# disabling PID and setting target on launch

Tags: ros, pid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/pid

When I start/restart a PID node, the setpoint is always set to 0, but the actual current position may be something else. If I want to make sure that my robot doesn't move back to 0 every time I restart the PID node, how would I give it an initial value, read from a node publishing the robots actual position? (the position publisher is on an arduino)

In other words, what I want to do is set the setpoint = current_position whenever the PID node starts/restarts.

These are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Start the Arduino (publishes actual position)
2. Move the robot manually to 5 meters (the arduino now publishes the current position as +5 meters)
3. Start the PID; the PID is automatically set to "enabled" with a set position of "0"
4. Robot moves to 0 without explicit instruction to do so

So I think the best solution would be to have an parameter to disable the PID on start. That way whatever logic enables it can make sure that the set-point is set correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276919/disabling-pid-and-setting-target-on-launch/) by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting the Arduino publisher to "[latch](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options)." Then the PID node should hear the most recently-published setpoint when it subscribes. (Hopefully the Arduino API allows latching...)

Edit: the latest commit will wait for you. [bitbucket.org/pid](https://bitbucket.org/AndyZe/pid/commits/all)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on 2017-12-05**:
the arduino does't issue the setpoint, it's set by a node running on the main system. The arduino does publish the current position of the robot though. I updated the question to be more specific.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-12-05**:
Ok. To be clear, if you clone the latest commit, you shouldn't have this problem anymore.